# How to customize addthis.com share/follow layers for mobile to fix it to the end of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, addthis

I have been trying hard to fix the share/follow banner provided by the `addthis.com` to the end of the page .

Like by default it just float over your website on the bottom of the phone . I was trying to fix this bellow the footer of my page .
Here is how it looks Please note the `Share|Follow` button at the bottom

[image]

But I want it to push it down to the bottom of the page

Some thing like this

[image]

I have tried following code

```
$(document).on("pagecreate",function () {
    addthis.layers({
        'theme': 'transparent',
            'share': {
            'position': 'left',
                'numPreferredServices': 5
        },
            'follow': {
            'services': [{
                'service': 'facebook',
                    'id': 'vikramabhushan'
            }, {
                'service': 'google_follow',
                    'id': 'vikrambanand'
            }]
        },
            'whatsnext': {},
            'recommended': {}
    });
});

$(document).on('pageshow',function(){
    var height = $('#outerPage').height();
    console.log('H: '+height);
    setTimeout(function () {
        //$('#at4m-mobile-container').addClass('bottom');
    $('body div.addthis-smartlayers-mobile').css("top",height-($('.foot').height()));
    }, 7500);   
});
```

so this script was sending the `div` `addthis-smartlayers-mobile` to the bottom of the page but it appears only after 6 seconds .

Can some one help me out to fix this thing.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/EfJg9/2/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: "it appears only after 6 seconds" - faster internet?

Comment: no bro :) see the code I was trying to catch the div `addthis-smartlayers-mobile`  but in the dom it was not available when the page was loading so I added setTimeout() and had to add delay there . as you can see in the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by just using css here is what i did

**CSS**

```
#at4m-dock {
    box-shadow: none !important;
    margin-bottom: -92% !important;
    position: absolute !important;

}
.at4m-dock-toggle {
    margin-bottom: -92% !important;
    position: absolute !important;
}
#at4m-mobile-container {
    position: initial !important;
    z-index: 9999999 !important;
}
```

And I removed the extra script so my script is something like this

```
$(document).on("pagecreate",function () {
    addthis.layers({
        'theme': 'transparent',
            'share': {
            'position': 'left',
                'numPreferredServices': 5
        },
            'follow': {
            'services': [{
                'service': 'facebook',
                    'id': 'vikramabhushan'
            }, {
                'service': 'google_follow',
                    'id': 'vikrambanand'
            }]
        },
            'whatsnext': {},
            'recommended': {}
    });
});
```

Here is a snapshot of it

Hope some one will be benefited

Thanks & Regards
[image]